# Using the word “forge” in a positive context

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

I came up with a two-word business name where the first word is “forge”. I imagined a craftman making something of great power and value, which carried the feeling I wanted to invoke, but I forgot about the other meaning of this word.

Is the word very ambiguous or primarily used in the context of counterfeit, or “it depends”?

Comment: "forgery" is primarily used in the context of counterfeiting, "forge" is ambiguous when used as a verb.

Comment: It's going to depend on context. CheckForge might set off alarms. CareerForge would give me the right idea, although it's possible some people would misinterpret.

Comment: You're forgetting the third usage, to move forward quickly - e.g. *forge ahead*. But any usage that invokes the meaning "create" will also risk the other interpretation "create illegally". What about switching your name around so *forge* is clearly a noun (and can't be confused with *forgery*), e.g. The Mind Forge?

Comment: Given the very popular and well-known service [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net), whose name has never suggested anything negative to me, I’d say there’s a good chance you’ll be fine with _forge_ as part of the name, as long as it’s not something obviously bad like _ForgeCheques_, as jimm101 says.

Comment: What about ForgePresence as in “build an [online] presence” (websites, social networks, marketing etc.)? Does that sound like using illegal methods and fakes to create the presence? :)